# passing file path to http handler as posted file in the format of context.request..files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to send a file to http handler in the form of context.request.files[index].Actually this is happen when we choose file from file upload controler.but my task is to do same thing with out file uploader controler.Here i am getting file path dynamically.i did not find till now how i can set(convert) this file path to context.request.files.we have any other options are there for sending this path to handler.i dont have a chance to edit handler.i must pass file path as a posted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you imagined is not possible. The file-upload control (`<input type="file"/>`) is controlled by the browser, which is the only THING in that context that can access the file that is to be uploaded. Some browsers won't even report the full path to your page, let alone the file content. So, even if you know the full path, you will not be able to touch the file, from within your script.

Now, some flash-uploaders can do this, but that's only because Adobe Player is installed on top of the operating system AND as a browser extension. However, these don't use HTML file-upload control (unless for a show or fallback for browsers w/o flash).

So, no, you cannot shove anything in Request.Files w/o the involvement of either file-upload control, or some Flash/Silverlight/Java-applet component.

Explain what you're trying to achieve. Maybe there's a different solution to your problem.